# Mobile nav (toggle menu) not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a mobile navigation that is a toggle menu, it has been posing a few problems, the first one being:

- Is not closed when page is loaded
- Will let me close, but won't let me reopen (or vice versa).

Have tried many combinations of telling the class to `display:none` and `display:block` but can't seem to figure this out.

Here is the jQuery I am using:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $(".menu-click").click(function(){
    $(".hs_cos_wrapper_type_menu").slideToggle(600);
    });
    });
```

The navigation can be found **[here](https://www.donorpro.com)** on the homepage.

Appreciate any advice or help you can give me to help me solve this issue, thanks!

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y7n2xan3/)** as well.

Comment: Try `$(".hs_cos_wrapper_type_menu").slideToggle(0);` in your `$( document ).ready()`

Comment: your menu is not working in the fiddle

Comment: you have no class `menu-click`. Try `ctrl-f` in the fiddle, there is none.

Comment: Yes there is, look towards the bottom, not sure why it doesn't let you `ctrl+f` search for it.

Comment: Yes I do, it's line 23.

Answer (score 0):

When looking at your code I asked myself: why is the span element not being grabbed by the slideToggle properly? This is because[slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) relies on an element having height and width. If you change your span element for a div and (for example) and assign it width 320px and height 100%, you will achieve the functionality you desire.

Let me know if you're still having problems after that and I can work on your code to give you an exact solution.

Also I did a search through the stackoverflow forums and found the following answer to a more general question under the same category, I hope it helps as well: [jquery slideToggle() not “sliding” in but out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502055/jquery-slidetoggle-not-sliding-in-but-out)

Comment: I can't touch some of the elements since this is built on the Hubspot COS. However, i was able to do what I needed by using `.css("display", "none");` coupled with `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: sounds like a troublesome work around, but it makes sense you need to rely on preventDefault. Either ways keep my comments in mind in case you have to deal with it in the future.

Comment: Believe me, it's more bulky than I would have liked, but the situation I am in (going from hardcoded HTML) to the COS's nav builder, really messed up the structure as it added a ton of classes that I can't change or edit. All is well now, will keep yours in mind for the future!